# Php preg_match sql update clause pattern

Tags: php, sql, pattern-matching, preg-match

I want to match an SQL query in order to capture different fields:

```
update nabi set fjfhj where jjj;
```

- `table` *required* - here nabi
- `columns` *required* - here fjfhj
- `where` *optional* - here jjj

Currently I have:

```
/^update\s+(?<table>[a-z_]+)\s+set(?<columns>.*?)(\s+where\s+(?<where>.*?))?;?$/si
```

**my problem is that where clause maybe empty!!!**

But where clause does not match properly! Here is an [online example](https://regex101.com/r/jG6lF0/1).

It's impossible ?

Comment: What are you trying to find with this pattern? Show us some samples and require results.

Comment: No, it's not clear. Do you want to match the keywords and/or the values? Is it suppose to match any update-query or only some specific ones always looking the same? Multiple set values/wheres? (right now, it's very limited since you're not matching on numbers, equal signs, back ticks, multiple columns etc.).

Comment: Ok. So it should be dynamic. That goes way beyond my regex skills. A query can be quite complicated (escaped quotes in quotes as an example). That's not an easy task. But for future reference: *be more clear in your question what you actually are trying to accomplish so we don't waste our time answering the wrong question!*

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/jG6lF0/3

Comment: I tried to reformulate, but I still don't understand whether the whole where clause should be optional, or whether there can be an empty where clause? Also from the example it's not clear whether you possibly want a where clause with whitespace? If my answer doesn't work for you, please give a example string on which I can test.

Answer (score 0):

Looking back at it, if I understand well you want to parse MYSQL queries in php. Note that if you want to do this properly, you need a parser, a regular expression won't do, because SQL syntax is way to complex. I see that there is a php library available though which might save you:

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/9091-PHP-Parse-MySQL-queries-into-tokens.html